# Passing array as a parameter with its size inside brackets

Tags: c, arrays

Is defining a function this way legal or helpful in any way?

```
void f(int arr[ARR_SIZE])
```

Comment: It's legal, but it doesn't really do anything, and it's potentially misleading.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

It's legal (assuming that `ARR_SIZE` is a positive integral type), and is perhaps a useful annotation, although confusing as it seems to make a false promise. On balance I wouldn't use it.

It *doesn't* mean that `arr` is an array of that size: `arr` is *still* an `int*` (due to pointer decay) and all size information is lost.

Far better then to write

```
void f(int* arr, size_t n)
```

with `f(arr, ARR_SIZE)` at the calling site, or `f(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))` if the non-decayed type of `arr` is available.

Comment: I personally appreciate *empty* brackets to at least denote that I expect a pointer to some array, whereas, in contrast, I use pointer syntax to denote pointers to a single object.

Answer (score 2):

I see one place where passing the (minimum) size can be useful:

```
void bar(int myArray[static 10]){...}
```

This tells the compiler that it should assume that the array passed to `bar` has at least 10 elements and can emit a warning if it is not the case:

```
int a[9];
bar(a);
```

returns:

```
warning: array argument is too small; contains 9 elements, callee requires at least 10 [-Warray-bounds]
    bar(a);
^   ~
```

[More info](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Legal - yes. Helpful? Not really. Look at this:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 4
int arr[ARR_SIZE], arr2[345];
f(arr); //works
f(arr2); //also works, compiler doesn't care about what size you specified in the []
```

This means that you still need to pass the size as a separate parameter:

```
void f2(int arr[ARR_SIZE], int size);
```

You can then call this function like this:

```
f2(arr, ARR_SIZE); //works
f2(arr2, 345); //works
```

So, don't use this syntax. The recommended prototypes are:

```
int f(int arr[], int size);
int f(int* arr, int size);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr` in this function is a pointer, for bounds check better pass size of the array as another parameter.

```
int fun(int *arr, int siz_arr) //function definition
{
     //.....
}



fun(arr,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); //function call for
```

Answer (score 0):

In 
`void f(int arr[ARR_SIZE]);`, `ARR_SIZE` is practically as good as a comment except the compiler will also verify that `ARR_SIZE` is either empty or a positive (>=0) integer constant.

Then it's 100% equivalent to `void f(int *arr);`.

C11 has `void f(int arr[static ARR_SIZE]);` where you can effectively require that the function only be passed pointers to the first element of arrays that have at least `ARR_SIZE` members (where `ARR_SIZE` must be a positive integer constant). E.g., `void take_nonnull(int arr[static 1]);` or `void take_at_least2(int arr[static 2]);`. Compilers may or may not issue diagnostics about subsequent calls to `f` that violate such a requirement (clang routinely does, gcc doesn't).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but ARR_SIZE must be defined at compile time, like this:
    `#define ARR_SIZE 3
void f(int arr[ARR_SIZE]){}`

Comment: You don't need that – it's equivalent to `int *arr`.

Comment: If you are talking about ARR_SIZE, you will have to initialize it. Insert the function prototype specified by the author and the compiler will give you an error: use of undeclared identifier 'ARR_SIZE'. If you are talking about passing an array, then yes the compiler will create a similar input. But the author asked whether it is possible to do so - yes it is. If only he had asked whether to do this, the answer would be different.